# Convert .doc to .html with google docs and php

Tags: php, html, google-docs-api, zend-framework

I'm trying to convert a word document to HTML on upload using zend and Google API. I'm always getting an error. I can upload the file to my Google account, but then I'm not beeing able to save it as HTML and then bring it back to my server. I'm using php and my server is Linux.

Does anyone ever done this?

Thank's in advance.

**EDIT:**

convert.php:

```
$argv = array("","","","achim.doc","stocklist.html");

require_once 'ConvertDoc.php';

if(!file_exists($argv[3])){
    echo $argv[3]." :: file does not exists\n\n";exit;
}
googlecsv($argv[3],$argv[4],'');

function googlecsv($originalFilename, $newfile, $tempfile) {
    try{
        $staticSessionTokens=array();
        echo "$originalFilename, $newfile, $tempfile <br/>\n\n";
        // create converter with authentication
        $cdoc = new ConvertDoc('', '', $staticSessionTokens);
        // convert to csv, all worksheets.
        $cdoc->convert($originalFilename, $newfile, $tempfile, 'html', '');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "<b style='color:red;font-size:1em;'>ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."</b><br/>\n";
    }
}
```

ConverDoc.php:

```
<?php

$path = "/home/webqda/public_html/zend/library"; 
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Docs');


class ConvertDoc{
    // holds the service tokens
    private $_serviceSessionToken = array();
    private $_user = '';
    private $_pass = '';
    private $_debug = false;
    private $_curl = false;

    /**
     * construct
     *
     * @param  string $user The username, in e-mail address format, to authenticate
     * @param  string $pass The password for the user specified
     * @param  array $tokens Array of tokens for clientlogin authentication
     * @return void
     */
    function __construct($username,$passwd,$tokens=array()){
        $this->_user=$username;
        $this->_pass=$passwd;
        foreach($tokens as $service=>$token){
            $this->set_service_token($service,$token);
        }
    }

    function debug($message){
        if($this->_debug)
            echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' :: '.$message."  <br/>\n";
    }

    /**
     * convert
     *
     * @param  string           $filename              the file name (either direct path to file or name of file with $tempfile holding the path to actual tmp file
     * @param  string           $newfilename           save as this file name
     * @param  string           $tempfile              file location if upload (/tmp/...)
     * @param  string           $format                format of file to download
     *                                                 http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets
     * @param  string           $gid                   The gid parameter is an absolute identifier for worksheets
     *                                                 for spreadsheets (if not numberic it will download entire workbook as one sheet)
     * @return void
     */
    function convert($filename, $newfilename='', $tempfile='',$format='html',$gid=0){
        $this->debug('convert file');
        // authenticate to docs list (wordly)
        $client = $this->getClientLoginHttpClient(Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);


        $docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
        $this->debug('authenticated');

        // upload temporary file to ggl
        $newDoc = $this->uploadDocument($docs, $filename, $tempfile);
        $this->debug('uploaded');
        // get the content source url
        $src = $newDoc->content->getSrc();
        // download the data to the new filename
        if($this->_curl){
            $content = $this->curlSrc($src, $format, $gid, $newfilename);
        } else {
            $content = $this->downloadSrc($src, $format, $gid, $newfilename);
        }
        $this->debug('downloaded');
        // delete the temporary file on ggl
        $newDoc->delete();
        $this->debug('deleted');
    }

    /**
     * set_service_token
     *
     * @param  string $service Which service to authenticate against.
     * @param  string $token Token for the service identified
     * @return void
     */
    function set_service_token($service,$token){
        //echo "$service :: $token    <br/>\n";
        $this->_serviceSessionToken[$service] = trim($token);// make sure it is clean.
    }

    /**
     * get_service_token
     *
     * @param  string $service Which service to authenticate against.
     * @return string
     */
    function get_service_token($service){
        if(!empty($this->_serviceSessionToken[$service])){
            //echo "$service :: ".$this->_serviceSessionToken[$service]."    <br/>\n";
            return $this->_serviceSessionToken[$service];
        }
        throw new Exception("session token not found for service {$service}\n");
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a HTTP client object with the appropriate headers for communicating
     * with Google using the ClientLogin credentials supplied.
     *
     * @param  string $service Which service to authenticate against.
     * @return Zend_Http_Client
     */
    function getClientLoginHttpClient($service='writely'){
        try{
            $token = $this->get_service_token($service);
            $this->debug('token');
            $client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();
            $client->setClientLoginToken($token);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            // no token found so make it.
            $this->debug('newtoken');
            $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($this->_user, $this->_pass, $service);
            $this->set_service_token($service,$client->getClientLoginToken());  
            /*
                    example on how to catch exceptions, not doing it here, the app needs to handle it.
                    try {
                        $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($this->_user, $this->_pass, $service);
                    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $e) {
                        echo "Error: Unable to authenticate. Please check your";
                        echo " credentials.\n";
                        exit(1);
                    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $e) {
                        echo 'CAPTCHA answer required to login';
                        echo $e->getCaptchaUrl();
                        exit;
                        // http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin.html
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo 'Unknown Exception';
                        exit;
                    }
            */
        }
        $config = array(
            'timeout' => 60 /* timeout after 60 seconds */
        );        
        $client->setConfig($config);
        return $client;

    }


    /**
     * Upload the specified document
     *
     * @param  Zend_Gdata_Docs $docs                  The service object to use for communicating with
     *                                                the Google Documents server.
     * @param  string          $originalFileName      The name of the file to be uploaded. The mime type
     *                                                of the file is determined from the extension on
     *                                                this file name. For example, test.csv is uploaded
     *                                                as a comma seperated volume and converted into a
     *                                                spreadsheet.
     * @param  string          $temporaryFileLocation (optional) The file in which the data for the
     *                                                document is stored. This is used when the file has
     *                                                been uploaded from the client's machine to the
     *                                                server and is stored in a temporary file which
     *                                                does not have an extension. If this parameter is
     *                                                null, the file is read from the originalFileName.
     * @return Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry
     */
    private function uploadDocument($docs, $originalFileName, $temporaryFileLocation=false) {
        $fileToUpload = $originalFileName;
        if ($temporaryFileLocation) {
            $fileToUpload = $temporaryFileLocation;
        }
        // get mimetype from original file name
        $filenameParts = explode('.', $originalFileName);
        $fileExtension = end($filenameParts);
        $mimeType = Zend_Gdata_Docs::lookupMimeType($fileExtension);
        if(!$mimeType){
            $mimeType = $this->mimetype($fileToUpload);
        }
        if(!$mimeType){
            throw new Exception("No Mime Type!");
            return false;
        }

        // Upload the file and convert it into a Google Document. The original
        // file name is used as the title of the document and the mime type
        // is determined based on the extension on the original file name.
        $e=true;
        $counter=0;
        while($e && $counter<10){
            try {
                $this->debug('upload');
                $newDocumentEntry = $docs->uploadFile($fileToUpload, $originalFileName, $mimeType, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI);
                $e=false;
            } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e){
                $r = $e->getResponse();
                if($r->getStatus() == '408'){
                    // timed out
                    $counter++;
                    $this->debug('try again');
                } else {
                    echo "<b style='color:red;font-size:1em;'>ERROR: ".$r->getMessage()." : ".$r->getBody()."</b><br/>\n";
                    $counter=10;// stop loop
                }                
                $e=true;
            }
        }
        if($counter==10){
            throw new Exception("failed to upload file");
            return false;
        }
        return $newDocumentEntry;
    }

    /**
     * get the mimetype for the file
     *
     * @param  string          $file               Link to the source file to download
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function mimetype($file){
        if(class_exists('finfo')){
            // new way, must be installed on php
            $this->finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME,'/usr/share/file/magic'); // use to return mime type ala mimetype extension
            if(!$this->finfo){
                $mimetype='unknown';
            } else {
                $mimetype = $this->finfo->file($file);
            }
        } else {
            $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
        }
        return $mimetype;
    }

    /**
     * Upload the specified document
     *
     * @param  string          $src_url               Link to the source file to download
     * @param  string          $format                format of file to download
     *                                                http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets
     * @param  string          $gid                   The gid parameter is an absolute identifier for worksheets
     *                                                for spreadsheets (if not numberic it will download entire workbook as one sheet)
     *
     *
     * @return Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry
     */
    private function downloadSrc($src_url, $format='html', $gid=0, $file=false) {
        // find service based on url
        $service = $this->src_url_service($src_url);
        // authenticate to service
        $this->getClientLoginHttpClient($service);
        // get the token from the service
        $sessionToken = $this->get_service_token($service);
        // now try to do our thing...
        $opts = array(  
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'GET',  
                'header' => "GData-Version: 3.0\r\n".  
                "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$sessionToken\r\n"
            )  
        );  
        // BUILD URL
        $src_url =  $src_url . '&chrome=false';
        if($format){
            $src_url =  $src_url . '&format='.$format.'&exportFormat='.$format.'';
        }
        if(is_numeric($gid)){
            $src_url =  $src_url . '&gid='.$gid.'';
        }
        // GET DATA
        $data = file_get_contents($src_url, false, stream_context_create($opts));

        if($file){
            file_put_contents($file,$data);
        }
        return $data;
    }  

    /**
     * Upload the specified document
     *
     * @param  string          $src_url               Link to the source file to download
     * @param  string          $format                format of file to download
     *                                                http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets
     * @param  string          $gid                   The gid parameter is an absolute identifier for worksheets
     *                                                for spreadsheets (if not numberic it will download entire workbook as one sheet)
     * @param  string          $file                  location of the file to save the data to
     *
     *
     * @return Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry
     */
    // curl -o tmp1 -H "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth={authcode}" "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={dockey}&exportFormat={format}"
    private function curlSrc($src_url, $format='html', $gid=0, $file=false){
        // find service based on url
        $service = $this->src_url_service($src_url);
        // authenticate to service
        $this->getClientLoginHttpClient($service);
        // get the token from the service
        $sessionToken = $this->get_service_token($service);
        // now try to do our thing...
        if($file){ // open file if saving to file.
            $file = fopen($file,"w+");
        }
        // BUILD URL
        $src_url =  $src_url . '&chrome=false';
        if($format){
            $src_url =  $src_url . '&format='.$format.'&exportFormat='.$format.'';
        }
        if(is_numeric($gid)){
            $src_url =  $src_url . '&gid='.$gid.'';
        }
        // INIT CURL
        $curl = curl_init($src_url);
        // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6
        // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/
        $header[] = "GData-Version: 3.0";
        $header[] = "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$sessionToken";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);// follow redirects!!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true); // TRUE to track the handle's request string. 

        if($file){
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE,$file); // file to write output to
            $data = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
        } else {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // output to variable
            $data = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
        }

        // debug info
        if($this->_debug){
            echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
            var_dump($data);
        }

        curl_close($curl); // close the connection
        return $data;
    }

    private function src_url_service($src_url){
        if(stristr($src_url,'spreadsheet')){
            return Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
        } else {
            return Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
        }
        // not sure how to handle pdg with Zend.

        // http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs
    }

}
```

This should convert the `achim.doc` file to `stocklist.html`, but instead I get the `stocklist.html` file, but the content is Google docs login page.

Comment: What's the error? Provide more info and/or code snippets

Comment: Edited the post above with code. Thank you!